# How to use exuberant ctags with python?

Tags: python, tags

I followed instructions here:
https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags

I've enabled the following:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode 'python-mode)
              (ggtags-mode 1))))
```

However, when I activate `ggtags-mode`, and try to use `M-.` on an item, global always returns 0 matches.  I have pygments installed, and I have a GGTAGS file, but it doesn't seem to find any matches on even simple functions like `open()`.

When I use `elpy-mode`, however, I can use `M-.` and get exactly the behavior I expect.  I am interested in getting exuberant tags to work rather than python because I understand it is designed to work multi-language: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html including python.

Comment: Does python-mode run c-mode-common-hook?  I would have thought you should add your code to prog-mode-hook instead.

Comment: Can you explain what that means please?

Comment: Substitute prog-mode-hook for c-mode-common-book in your code above. Then the code should run when you open a python file.